# Consider defining bean of type authentication manager

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I am trying implement `jwt` authentication with spring security but I am getting following error :-

```
java version - 1.8
spring version - 2.3.3.RELEASE

Description:

Field authenticationManager in com.exam.skillassess.controller.AuthenticationController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.
```

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration.
```

I have read all related answers and tried solutions provided but still getting error:-

this is authentication controller class ->

```
@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    
    @PostMapping("/generate-token")
    public ResponseEntity<?> generateToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest request) throws Exception{
        
        try {
            authenticate(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword());
            
        }catch(UsernameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("User not found Exception");
        }
        UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(request.getUsername());
        String token = this.jwtUtils.generateToken(userDetails);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));
    }
    
    private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));  
        }catch(DisabledException e) {
            throw new Exception("User Disabled" + e.getMessage());
        }catch(BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new Exception("Bad Credentials" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is security configuration class ->

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration

public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unAuthorizedHandler;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(this.userDetailsServiceImpl).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
        .cors()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/generate-token", "/user/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unAuthorizedHandler)
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
    
}
```

pom.xml ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/><!--lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.exam</groupId>
    <artifactId>skillassess</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>skillassess</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Security dependencies for jwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Security dependencies for jwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Yes i have added `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` in MySecurityConfig class

Comment: i just looked one more time on your code and i gave a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**By default, spring creates the bean's name the same as the bean initializing method name. So in your project, spring creates a bean of type `AuthenticationManager` named as `authenticationManagerBean`.**

In your controller(`AuthenticationController`) where you inject `AuthenticationManager` replace:

```
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```

to

```
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean;
```

OR use the `@Qualifier` in your controller class:

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```

**UPDATE**

The Problem why application not found `AuthenticationManager` **it is in your project structure**, you are declaring next one structure:

```
package config;
```

[image: wrong structure]

**That is outside and Spring can not scan declared `Bean` there**

To fix it:

Move your `config` package under `skillassess`.

Something like this:

[image: correct]

```
package com.exam.skillassess.config;
```

[structuring-your-code](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.structuring-your-code)

Another approach is to add one more annotation on **SkillassessApplication** class that will scan your both packages

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "config", "com.exam.skillassess"
})
```

Comment: I am still getting error

Exception in thread "task-2" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
 
Field authenticationManagerBean in com.exam.skillassess.controller.AuthenticationController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.

Comment: Can you update your question with maven/gradle dependency tree ?

Comment: dependency tree i mean  pom.xml or gradle build file, where is declared spring dependency that have used your project

Comment: I have added pom.xml, can you please check and help

Comment: i just tried your code all work great spring is up in running, i dont know, maybe you will add your current impl on github and i will try with your impl. One more suggestion  in your project execute please `mvn clean install` and rerun your project

Comment: https://github.com/tk84274/skillassess-backend/tree/skillassess1.0.0

Comment: i just updated my answer, the problem was in your project structure, have a look at official documentation about how spring scan the packages.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was stuck for around 20 days, but couldn't figure it out. I kind of knew I must have done something very stupid. Thank you so much for your help. I could not have figured it out without you.

Comment: if it was helpful, you can up vote my answer and also accept it ))))